# Do I respect schema markup best practice?

Tags: seo, schema.org, markup

I'm trying to find info on the web about the best practice about schema markup and I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right or wrong.

Here's what I've done :

1. I took all reviews (and ratings) from Facebook and google places and
   I've put them on my web site in a plugin that automatically create the
   schema markup for product and local business with the 5 star rating
   system.
2. I've put the reviews of each services into the service pages
   Here is the result (into the structured data testing tool):
   https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fkinesante.ca%252Fkinesitherapie-montreal%252F
3. Did the same for 2 other services.
4. Then on my homepage I aggregated all the reviews from all my services and put them into a schema.org/localbusiness markup.
   https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fkinesante.ca%252F

So my questions are:

1. Do I respect the best practice?
2. Can I copy reviews from another website into my own to show what my customers think about my business?
3. Can I aggreate the reviews from 3 different services into a global business review?
4. Will I be rich someday ?

Answer (score 1):

All thins are Good, But Copy others Website Review is not good ethics for Schema. Ask review from your Customers. If the Ratio of Customer review is low and you need more so offer them discount and deal in exchange of review and rating. 
Yes you will, Rich is on Luck and HardWork.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer! Since I made thoses changes (last week) I still did not get back the star rating in the search results. DO you think it is because of the bad ethics of copying the reviews or it is just a normal validation time?

Comment: Yes it takes time. But copy review is not good. May be it effect later. But it will.